# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Flickity'. import call expects exactly one argument

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, import, flickity

I am creating a simple image slider using Flickity with Vue.js. However, whenever I try to import it into my script file as per the instructions here: https://github.com/drewjbartlett/vue-flickity, it gives me the above error. This is my code so far:

index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Product App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <flickity ref="flickity" :options="flickityOptions">
      <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="./assets/jer_japan_01.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="./assets/jer_japan_02.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="./assets/jer_japan_03.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="./assets/jer_japan_04.jpg" alt=""></div>
      <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="./assets/jer_japan_05.jpg" alt=""></div>
    </flickity>

    <button @click="previous()">Custom Previous Button</button>
    <button @click="next()">Custom Next Button</button>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js file:

```
import Flickity from 'vue-flickity';

new Vue({
  components: {
    Flickity
  },
  
  data() {
    return {
      flickityOptions: {
        initialIndex: 3,
        prevNextButtons: false,
        pageDots: false,
        wrapAround: true
      }
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    next() {
      this.$refs.flickity.next();
    },
    
    previous() {
      this.$refs.flickity.previous();
    }
  }
});
```

[Here is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00PrV.png)

Comment: How is your project set up?  You're using Vue over CDN but your script is an es6 module.  Maybe you can show main.js too.

Comment: I’m super new to this, so not sure how to answer that, sorry! Are you able to elaborate on your question? I have edited my post however as it is the main.js file I’m showing, I put ‘script’ by mistake.

Comment: The import is a single file component, typically used with a build tool like Vue CLI.  So you should create your project with Vue CLI to use it

Comment: Got it! Thank you, I will give that a go in the morning.

Comment: Did you solve this already? I have a similar problem when using the Simple upload adapter from ckeditor, by using an import statement in the script element in the blade file of Laravel 8, I get the same error but with `SimpleUploadAdapter` instead of your `Flickity`.